# any other site(s) like this one?

Tags: c

this site is extremely cool ( http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=strncpy  ) but a bit unformatted, it shows many (and this means a lot) of C functions with params , example etc. the prototype example of the function is very bad anyway. do you know other sites as complete or more than this one? i recall there's one site with a dice icon that has many C functions.
thanks

Comment: I don't think your question is appropriate for the site, but if you want a quick overview of C I recommend http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/101/ and of course K&R

Comment: [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

Comment: Google for it? I just tried "c reference" and you get that cplusplus.com site on second place! (Not mentioning other possible sites.) I think some ppl use SO instead of google.

Comment: closed as not a real question by Yasir Arsanukaev, Mat, Mitch Wheat, Prasoon Saurav, Radek Pro-Grammer 12 hours ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use the [c library section](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/) of cplusplus.com.

Comment: +1 Over the years, I've found cplusplus's references to be an impecable resource.

Answer (score -1):

The site you're thinking of is [linux.die.net](http://linux.die.net/). Apple also [has one](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/). They just contain man pages for their given operating systems. You can use `man <section> <name>` at a *nix prompt to read them, where `<section>` is 2, 3, or 3p depending on the specific name.

Comment: That would not be my problem.

Comment: yes sir it's not your problem.